# Isn't "fog" uncountable when referring to a weather phenomenon?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

I came across an example sentence on [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fog):

> a climate marked by **heavy fogs**

Isn't *fog* a noncount noun when used to refer to weather, according to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fog). The [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fog) and the [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/fog_1) also mention that it can be used in singular in constructions such as "a fog of dust". So is the plural usage in the Merriam Webster sentence grammatical?

Comment: It is both countable and uncountable.

Comment: If "We had **three fogs** last winter" is acceptable, then it can be a count noun.

Comment: [Related question about "a fog"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151780/there-is-a-fog-is-the-noun-used-correctly).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**fog** the weather phenomenon is uncountable.

> The cove was shrouded in fog.

**fog** the *recurrent* weather phenomenon is countable.

> This low-lying district is subject to fogs, some so thick you cannot see more than ten feet in front of you.

Or perhaps this:

> Your frequent mental fogs are beginning to  trouble me, dear.

Comment: Same goes for *rains*, *snows*, *winds*, and various other weather phenomena.

Answer (score 1):

Of your three dictionaries, the Cambridge Dictionary says that 'fog' is uncountable in British usage, and countable or uncountable in US usage. The Oxford Dictionaries site says it is a mass (uncountable) noun; MacMillan says it is countable or uncountable.

Collins Dictionary calls it a 'variable noun' and gives a countable usage example very similar to yours = "These ocean fogs can last for days." https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fog

Longman Dictionary says it is countable or uncountable.
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/fog

My own experience is that the usage 'fogs' is mainly found in older British texts (pre-1800) and in modern US usage in a maritime context.